# How to enumerate vertices in OpenGL

Tags: 3d, mesh

I'm new to OpenGL and my question seems to be very simple, but I haven't found propper inforamtion yet.

I'm trying to build my own cone by rotating a triangle around the y-axis.

I've got some (x,y) coordinates which describes the triangle. As I understood, I have to convert them to `(x,y,z)` like `(x*cos(alpha), x*sin(alpha),y)`, where `alpha` is between `[0, 2Pi]` with some step (let it be `Pi/36`)

Next, I have to enumerate obtained vertices to tell OpenGL how to connect them.

So, my question is about how to enumerate them correctly.

Comment: did you actually draw anything yet ? (for example do you use glVertex, or VBO, etc, or have you no idea of what I'm talking)

Comment: @Guiroux , To be honest, I'm not using OpenGL propperly. I'm using OpenSceneGraph, but it is only a library around OpenGL.I have vertex array with all calculated vertices and another array which I should fill up with right indexes of vertices from first array, then I set them to a geometry and it starts to draw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has nothing to do with OpenGL;
This cone will be without basis.

First create vertices

```
int density = 10;
float3 vertices[];
vertices.add(float3(0,0,1));
for(int i=0; i<=density; i++) {
    float alpha = i*2*PI/density
    vertices.add(float3(cos(alpha), sin(alpha), 0));
}
```

Then create indices and triangles

```
int indices[];
for(int i=0; i<density; i++) {
    //add triangle
    indices.add(0);
    indices.add(i);
    indices.add(i+1);
}
```

Then you have to use data from `vertices[]` and `indices[]` during drawing.

Comment: Can you explain why does your vertex `float3(cos(alpha), sin(alpha), 0)` has zero `z` coordinate?

Comment: I've assumed that z is for height, so the cone has height from 0 to 1